# How to distinguish keypress Jquery event between on-screen keyboard and physical keyboard in NW.exe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard, node-webkit

I am developing an app running in nodewebkit. Basically, I want to support the on screen keyboard(tabtip.exe) for touch screen. While, if the user has uses a physical keyboard, I want to hind the on-screen keyboard. But now I cannot distinguish the physical keyboard and on screen keyboard keypress event, every time the user press a key from on screen keyboard, it will also trigger the keypress event and hide the on screen keyboard as well.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that when the user presses a key from physical keyboard, I want to hide the on-screen keyboard. That is the reason why I asked this question.

Answer (score 0):

You may have answered your own question.
Just see if tabtip.exe is running by doing something like this to return a list of running processes.

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('tasklist', function(error, stdout, stderr) {
  if (error) {
    console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
    return;
  }
  console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
  console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
});
```